# python - How do I execute this function syntax?

Tags: python, return

```
def swap_value(x,y):    
    temp = x
    x = y
    y = temp
    return

swap_value(3,4)
```

I tried it like this. But it didn't work

Comment: What is the expected effect of this function?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: you're not returning anything?

Comment: `3` and `4` are constants. You should assign them to variables e.g `n1`, `n2` and then call `swap_value(n1,n2)`. But then again, you do not seem to return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is not returning anything, so maybe you want to return a tuple like:

```
def swap_value(x, y):
    temp = x
    x = y
    y = temp
    return x, y
```

Wich is a more verbose way of just doing:

```
def swap_value(x, y):
    return y, x
```

Problem with the above methods is you're not doing a proper swapping, test below:

```
x, y = 3, 4
print(swap_value(x, y))
print(x, y)
```

The most pythonic way to swap values in python would be using a simple oneliner, this would be the minimal pythonic way to swap values, no need to wrap swapping into a function (unless the swap did something else):

```
x, y = 3, 4
x, y = y, x
print(x, y)
```

Answer (score 4):

How about just 'x,y = y,x' ? There is no need for a separate function.

Answer (score -2):

Please use below:

```
def swap_value(x,y):
    temp = x
    x = y
    y = temp
    return x,y
```

Comment: thats the same as `return y,x` which in turn is the same as `x,y = y,x` - no function needed....

Comment: @PatrickArtner of course, but my attempt was to correct OP's code.  DOnt know why this need a down voting

Comment: because you introduce not needed temp variables in not needed functions, therefor delivering bad pythonesque code - which I deemed not really helpfull. simply return y,x would be the "fix" if you really wanted a function to do this - but still the overhead of switching context is _bad_ usage of python